# How stable is System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ado.net

I am about to consider using SQLite in my .NET application. I am experienced with SQL Server, EF and ADO.NET; however, I have not knowledge of SQLite.

While I can learn SQLite in no time, I wanted to consult with the experts here and see how stable is System.Data.SQLite?

Is there any known frustration or issues with SQLite having memory leak issue?

Does it work okay with Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No issues, it has been around for at least 10 years.

It has basic support for EF6 (no Code First Migrations)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, SQLite works quite well with Entity Framework Core but I've only been using it for code first.

It is under active development as you can see from its NuGet page and its contribution graph on GitHub.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/

https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/graphs/contributors

For a list of SQLite limitations, see this page at doc.microsoft.com:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations